# Can radio buttons be selected through tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, input, tabs, radio-button

I created an options page with some tabs: https://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/subscriptions/BA/?p=02. How can I make it so that when a user selects a day, the radio button is already selected for the user?

Tabs are just in a ul list and inputs are in a div.

Answer (score 1):

Use a checked attribute to check the radio buttons by default.

```
<input type="radio" name="price" value="" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. But I'd actually like it so the radio button gets checked automatically when the day-tab gets clicked on. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: for that you can use jQuery. Here is an example fiddle to help you get started http://jsfiddle.net/anuragverma65/sko3myyg/

Comment: Thank you @anurag. That is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Load a JS function to catch the tab being activated which will "check" the radio button when it becomes active. Below will auto-check radioButton1 when tabs-1 is clicked:

```
$( "#tabs-1" ).on( "tabsbeforeload", function(event) {
        document.getElementById("radioButton1").checked = true;
} )
```